# Loading data into training set in Python

Tags: python, load

I need to create a training and test set over all the files in my 2 directories. But I am only able  to select one file. How to go through all the .npz files?

Images are stored in the image folder, following the format: `[patient_id].npz`. Each .npz file contains both scan and mask (3-d arrays), accessible by :

```
import numpy as np

archive = np.load('Train set/Images/patient_002.npz')
train_scan = archive['scan']
train_mask = archive['mask']

test_set = np.load('Test set/Images/patient_000.npz')
test_scan = test_set['scan']
test_mask = test_set['mask']
```

With the test_scan.shape and train_mask.shape as 3d matrices:

Out:

(92, 92, 92)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
import os
all_files = []
for _, _, file_name in os.walk('Train set/Images/'):
    all_files.extend(file_name)

all_files = [file_name for file_name in all_files if file_name.endswith('.npz')]
```

And then you can read all_files in a for loop. Hope this helps.